# Value of a number going up

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Right, i honestly have no idea what to even search to find this out! i have searched many phrases trying to find out and i keep coming back with nothing.

I have a client who has asked if it is possible to have a number like 2.00000000 and have it constantly going up at a variable speed. The task he wants is to have is for different users to have a number that keeps going up (for what reason i don't know, i said ill look into it for him to find out if there is a plugin or something).

But either way he wants it to b able to even while the user is offline the value still continues to go up.

Is there such a plugin to achieve this? cheers

Comment: If you have access to cronjobs, you could run one every few seconds and choose at random if you would like to update a value in the database or something similar

Comment: No need for a plugin, yes it can be done.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to run code every _x_ milliseconds? How to change what number is displayed? How to add a random value?

Comment: I dont see how you can look into it if you don't understand the client's needs. Poor client service on your part in my books.

Comment: @CodedMonkey wouldnt that put alot of stress on the server when there are may users and the server will need to update them?

Comment: @dragon it was passing question when i last spoke with him nothing to do with the current project i'm working with him on now and so i though i would take a bit of time to look into it. on our next meeting i would questions moreso the needs to get a more direct question than m veryopen aired question here

Comment: @user2570469 well that depends, I don't think running a simple script puts a lot of stress on the server (a couple of seconds is a bit much though), but I also kind of misread your question.

Comment: @user2570469 in the act of professionalism you should have stated that if it's unrelated to the project, you may take a look into it at a later date but would like to focus all attention on the current project

Answer (score 2):

If it is at variable speed couldn't he just check the `date time` at which he initialize the sequence and compare it to the time at which he checks the number. The difference in time would be that offset he would call `variable speed`

For example if he wanted the number to increase 10 every 24 hours then:

```
   double intialTimeInSeconds = //Whatever the Start time would be
   double amountGainedEverySecond = 24/10/60/60;
   double nowTime = //whatever time it is now;
   return (nowTime - initialTimeInSeconds)*amountGainedEverySecond;
```

Comment: thank you! it seems like the right way to go. I am giving it a try now and will let you know : thanks

Comment: Please upvote and/or click the check mark below the up/down error next to the post if you liked the answer.